# I am trying to find a specific Sci-Fi Board game I played once years ago

Tags: identify-this-game

I play many board games, this is not one of the obvious ones. I am trying to find the name of a game that I think went out of print.

1. It is a sci-fi game.
2. Every player is in charge of a faction.
3. You are all trying to colonize/exploit the same planet.
4. It is not *Terra Forming Mars* though the planet might be Mars. (There are fewer cards and more plastic pieces)
5. I think every player had their own rectangular play mat that represented their stakes/claims on the planet.
6. Trading resources was a critical part of the game. (The dynamic player influenced market is one of the biggest things I remember)
7. It might be considered more of a worker placement game.

**My memory is getting less clear about details after this point**

8. Play took place mostly on your own mat. The "central board" was more a market where players exchanges resources and bought "units" (mostly excavators or androids?).
9. I think the game initially came out in the 90s or earlier then got a reprint in the 2010s.
10. The set I played was newly opened in the 2010ish and had bright plastic pieces.
11. The theme/artistic style was slightly cartoonish.
12. I think it was 4 player max.

Comment: When you say "Sci-Phy" are you referring to "sci-fi" which is short for "science fiction", or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: Dune Imperium, First Martians, Outpost. Do you have anything else in mind how long it took, how complex it was, what the goal was or how it was tracked?

Comment: Component shape/style it is closest to First Martians. The resources you traded where represented as different coloured cubes. The resource collecting machine/harvester/driller token is similarly shaped to some of the figurines. But each player had 4 (ish) of their own. I feel like it was a 2-3 hour game. Though it might have been advertised as 60-90 mins. For me the complexity is a 5 or 6, but I play Twilight Imperium and Federation and Empire. I think the goal was VP or $$ structured like VP. Most actions consumed resources. Harvesting and then trading them at a good exchange are the goal.

Comment: There was an actual map board of hexs or squares that you could move/place units on. The edition I played has plastic 3D pieces for this.  The unit placement was mostly around what resources you could get.

Comment: It does sound like First Martians - but that’s a cooperative game and you seem to suggest this is competitive. First Martians is also new (well, 2017); it is based on the older Robinson Crusoe game, but that’s only from 2012. So not that then. It doesn’t sound like the original Dune, but the reprint angle makes it seem like a remote possibility?

Comment: There are visual similarities to First Martian, but the art style itself is way off ( to serious). Definity not Dune.